# Convert date column as row ID in r

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this

```
Id  date   TENAGA   SIME DARBY
1   00-01   5.6      10.9
2   00-02   4.0      2.0
3   00-03   4.1      6.8
4   00-04   2.3      1.3
5   00-05   8.7      3.5
```

I want to convert date column to Raw names like this

```
date   TENAGA     SIME DARBY
00-01   5.6        10.9
00-02   4.0         2.0
00-03   4.1         6.8
00-04   2.3         1.3
00-05   8.7         3.5
```

Comment: do you mean removing the first column?

Comment: No. first column is date. I want to use date as row ID. I think you understand what I mean by Row ID

Comment: no, we likely don't. do you mean use the character representation of the date as row _names_ ? Do you need that for some other, older R package operations? Are you sure the dates are unique? If not they can't be row names. You haven't provided the full problem statement.

Comment: I do not completely understand.  You still have a column header for date.  Do you want it to be a string?  Or do you want it to be the row names?

Comment: Sorry, If I make any wrong statement. I will correct. I got the solution and that is rownames(df) <- df$date

Comment: Should I write Row names instead row ID

Comment: @hrbrmstr sorry for the late reply. I have edited the question, I wrote row names instead of row id. I needed that because when I transpose the file I want date as a column name as I want to run cross-sectional regression  Hence I want to use this kind of formula for regression             fit4 <- lapply(names(df1), function(x){
  dd = tidy(lm(df1[[x]] ~ df2[[x]]))
  data.frame(name = x, dd)}) . However still I can not find regression coefficient of each period. I would be very happy if you can help me in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in following way.

```
rownames(df) <- df$date
```

This will make date column as ID.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use row.names fun and then delete actual column

> Row.names(df) <- df$date
>
> Df$date <- NULL